sync problem between map and layerswitcher
In my test page https://visiolittoral.fr/ANDROID_CARTE_IGN_2024_5.php?UNIK_COMMUNE=93105&LONGITUDE=-1.32&LATITUDE=46.15&ZOOM=12 I use several LeafLet features.
Among others, the ability to display geoJson data (lines 162 to 275).
The principle is to display geoJson data from three URLs that return the same geoJson structure.
Depending on the needs, it is possible to choose whether the layer will be shown or hidden on the map, but in both cases it will have to be included in the layerswitcher. (Lines 269 to 275).
In the current version of the code, I start with an addTo(map) for all layers, the addition in the layerswitcher, then, if need, I remove the layer from the map. I tried simply not to do the addTo for the visible=false, but that doesn't change the problem that I'm explaining to you now.
On the first display, the geoJson data visible=true (Commune and neighboring commune) are displayed correctly. To display the other visible=false (GPS), you must in theory open the LayerSwitcher, uncheck the "eye" to display the map.
That's the problem!
On the first display, the "eye" of the "GPS" is open in the layerSwitcher which means that the layer is displayed on the map, and this is not the case of course.
To find a perfect synchronization between map and layerswitcher, you have to click twice on the "eye", once to close it, once to open it.
There you go, since you didn't know what to do, I found you something to do!
Kind regards
Pascal
Phase 1

Phase 2

Phase 3


Edwin on https://groups.google.com/g/leaflet-js/c/12gFXqjaPKY found the solution.
You have to add force the state of the layers of the layerSwitcher with
layerSwitcher.setVisibility(geoJsonLayer, false)

The test page is updated.
A+
Pascal
